# how and why spring container building EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

i am using spring boot and trying to implement multiple datasources using spring jpa.

**Problem** when i run server then LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean builds JPA container for **Default** persistence unit .

i have excluded **HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class** from AutoConfiguration so it should not go for Default datasources? atleast thats what my understanding   is.

```
  2015-08-28 08:05:35.933  INFO 3764 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2015-08-28 08:05:35.943  INFO 3764 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
```

this is how i am running my application

```
 @SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
 @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })

public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer/*
                                                             * implements
                                                             * CommandLineRunner
                                                             */{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

This is how first Config file looks like :

```
  @Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "xx.xx.repository", entityManagerFactoryRef = "blueberryEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "blueberryTransactionManager")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class DbConfigBlueBerry {

    @Value("${spring.datasourceblueberry.driver-class-name}")
    String driverClassName = "";
    @Value("${spring.datasourceblueberry.url}")
    String url = "";
    @Value("${spring.datasourceblueberry.username}")
    String userName = "";
    @Value("${spring.datasourceblueberry.password}")
    String password = "";

    @Bean(name = "blueberryEntityManager")
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean(name = "blueberryEntityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(DataSourceBuilder.create().url(url)
                .driverClassName(driverClassName).username(userName)
                .password(password).build());

        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(R.Blueberry_PACKAGE);
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("blueberryPersistenceUnit");
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean(name = "blueberryTransactionManager")
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }
```

**Note:** 
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean builds entityManagerFactory for my defined datasource as well but after building Default one.

```
  Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'blueberryPersistenceUnit'
2015-08-28 08:05:36.925  INFO 3764 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: blueberryPersistenceUnit
    ...]
```

**My Doubts** 
whats the significance of Default PersistenceUnitInfo ?
From where it is building the Default PersistenceUnitInfo ? What am i missing ?

Please provide your valuable thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` already contains `@EnableAutoConfiguration` so maybe that is why it is not using your exclusion group. You might try to remove that annotation.

Comment: As you said i just tried that as well but it did not have any impact on default persistence .But thanks for telling me ,will keep in mind.